# How to calculate /tf in hector_slam?

Tags: ros, quadcopter, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am studying mapping with hector_slam and hector_mapping.

I run $ roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch, and $ rosbag play Team_Hector_MappingBox_RoboCup_2011_Rescue_Arena.bag --clock

Basing on the diagram of $rqt_graph, the mapping is performed on data from laser scan with respect to /tf data.
Does anyone know how to produce /tf data in this case? It looks like they only use IMU data somehow to estimate the transformation?

Thanks! I very appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200336/how-to-calculate-/tf-in-hector_slam?/) by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2015-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly, hector_slam is independent of /tf for laser ([watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8pdObV_df4)). You can simply have a laser attached to a computer and walk around to create a 2D map. I haven't used the bag file that you mentioned before, but usually the bag file should contain time stamped /tf data, or simply create a urdf.xacro config file for your system and load it using [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) to publish transforms.

---

Originally posted by [ajain](https://answers.ros.org/users/18985/ajain/) with karma: 281 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tn0432](https://answers.ros.org/users/21276/tn0432/) on 2015-01-06**:
Thank you for your response! Regarding the case of having a laser attached to a computer, I am struggling to make it work. I can receive and draw the laser data in rviz. But still cannot make a map with hector_slam. I think the problem is in defining the /tf frames. Hope you can help! Thanks